# How to read JSON response containing an array of objects of a user-defined class?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am developing a ASP.NET WebForms website that uses JQuery to fetch some data from a ASP.NET ASHX handler. This data is an array of objects of a class that is user-defined. Following is the code of Handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using WRG_2._1.WRGCore;

namespace WRG_2._1.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ResponseFetcher
    /// </summary>
    public class ResponseFetcher : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            List<Topic> comments = new List<Topic>() {
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },
                new Topic(){ Title=DateTime.Now.ToString() +":"+ DateTime.Now.Millisecond },

            };
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string sJSON = jss.Serialize(comments);
            context.Response.Write(sJSON);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am fetching data from JQuery Ajax like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var url = '/Handlers/ResponseFetcher.ashx';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data:
                    JSON.stringify({ val1: 2, val2: 3 })
                ,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: true,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    now = (new Date()).getTime();
                    if (localCache.exist(url)) {
                        tDiff = now - cacheTime;
                        if (tDiff < 20000) {
                            loadData(localCache.get(url));
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    localCache.set(url, jqXHR, loadData);
                }
            });

        });

        function loadData(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(data.responseJSON).each(function (i) {

                $('#responsecontainer').html = data.responseJSON[i].Title;
            });
        }
```

The function `loadData()` is getting the data perfectly. But its not adding it to `#responsecontainer` div. Please help!

Note that the class `Topic` can have null variables too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with parsing of JSON response. I converted my code of `loadData()` function to:

```
function loadData(data) {
            var resdata = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
            console.log(resdata[0].Title);

            $(resdata).each(function (i) {
                $('#responsecontainer').append(resdata[i].Title);
            });
        }
```

And now its working. Thanks to all those who answered my question. Your answers gave me this hint. :)

Comment: Inside the .each callback, the current array element will be assigned to 'this', so an alternative way to achieve the same thing is: $('#responsecontainer').append(this.Title);

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's .html is a method. You use it as a setter by passing the new value as the argument:

```
$('#responsecontainer').html(data.responseJSON[i].Title);
```

But this will iteratively fill #responsecontainer with each .Title in your data.reponseJSON objects, with each .Title replacing the last .Title, so you'll only ever see the last .Title.  You probably want to append:

```
$('#responsecontainer').append(data.responseJSON[i].Title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning it on that way you really have that *responseJSON* property on the *data* object?

on my experiences returning it on that way i've got the results directly on the *data* object:

```
$(data).each(function (i) {
    $('#responsecontainer').append(data[i].Title);
});
```